# Symfony2 - How to create list checkbox in twig from roles, table Group, FOSUserBundle

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox

I want to create a checkbox list with roles in table `Group`, one checkbox is a role.
I have code override `GroupFormType.php`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    $builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => ???,//i don't know how to get roles in database
        'empty_value' => false,
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'required'  => false,
    ));
}
```

If I do that  `'choices' => array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two')`, it works!
Field roles in database with comment (DC2Type:array)

Then, I created `AddRolesFieldSubscriber` with the following code:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    // Tells the dispatcher that we want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
    // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
    return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
}

public function preSetData(DataEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();


    // During form creation setData() is called with null as an argument
    // by the FormBuilder constructor. We're only concerned with when
    // setData is called with an actual Entity object in it (whether new,
    // or fetched with Doctrine). This if statement let's us skip right
    // over the null condition.
    if (null === $data) {
        return;
    }

        $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('roles', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => $data->getRoles(),
                'empty_value' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required'  => false,
        )));
}
```

And change `GroupFormType.php`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $subscriber = new AddRolesFieldSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory());
    $builder->addEventSubscriber($subscriber);
}
```

But I got an exception:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in xxx\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList.php line 457
>   500 Internal Server Error - ErrorException

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your `createNamed()` call. The third option here is *not* the options array, but the initial value of the field.